# Run MongoDB in Perl

Tags: perl, mongodb

How to convert the following command in perl?

```
dn.runCommand({group : {
    "ns"      : "stocks",
    "key"     : "date",
    "initial" : {"time" : 0},
    "$reduce" : function(doc, prev) {
        if ( doc.time > prev.time ) {
            prev.time  = doc.time;
            prev.price = doc.price;
            }
        },
    "condition" : {"day" : { "$gt" : "2020/09/30 }}
    }}
)
```

Regards.

Comment: I've never used MongoDB so I don't have any specific help, but I'd suggest that using the [MongoDB module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/) from CPAN would be a good start.

Comment: I am a newbie, so I never think about writing my own mongodb driver. If you have a little experience with cpan mongodb, you must know that the command in mongo console is different from the cpan mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the below code, but it maybe works.

```
use MongoDB;
my $db = MongoDB::Connection->new->test;
$db->run_command({
group => {
    "ns"      => "stocks",
    "key"     => "date",
    "initial" => {"time" => 0},
    '$reduce' => 'function(doc, prev) {
         if ( doc.time > prev.time ) {
            prev.time  = doc.time;
            prev.price = doc.price;
         }
    }',
    "condition" => {"day" => { '$gt' => "2020/09/30" }}
}}
);
```